# Kill command refuses to work when using 'screen' utility what am I doing wrong?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, macintosh, lubuntu

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> does nothing I've tried to get it to work but nothing happens no confirmation prompt shows at the bottom I looked up the file .screenrc and I'm considering changing the keys but I would like to know why it's not working first.

I'm on a 2009 MBP currently running Lubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) LXQT version 0.17.0 on it I have not changed the layout of my keys.

**Edit:**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> doesn't work either but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> does, not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, then release those keys, then press <kbd>k</kbd> alone (or with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>k</kbd> is "destroy current window". But it only works if you have multiple windows.

Comment: Is there anyway I can give you credit on another stacexchange? I asked the same question on ubuntus version.